# What list is the Bible talking about for widows over 60?

Tags: 1-timothy

Is is a pension or retirement list? money? security?

1 Timothy 5:8-10 NET

> No widow should be put on the list unless she is at least sixty years
>   old, was the wife of one husband

Answer (score 2):

Early Christian societies kept track of the widows, orphans, and other people in their local area who needed the help of the body.  Part of standard Christian action, then as now, was to render assitance to those who had no resources for themselves. Here, Paul is refering to that list.

To answer your question even more directly, in the absence of a state that provides these functions (as is now the case), yes, it was the "pension" list of today.

Paul is suggesting that younger widows not be put on the list, but rather they should remarry so as not to be a long term obligation of the church.

Comment: i see. so no longer practiced today?